# MySQL query freezes

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a following query

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    Products.Product_name
    FROM Order_details
    INNER JOIN Products
    ON Products.Product_codenumber = Order_details.Product_codenumber
    INNER JOIN Orders
    ON Order_details.Order_ID = Orders.Order_ID
    INNER JOIN Customers
    ON Orders.Customer_ID = Customers.Customer_ID
    INNER JOIN Discount_cards
    ON Discount_cards.Phone_number = Customers.Login
    WHERE Orders.Status_ID = '5'
    AND (DATE(Orders.Time) BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date')
```

that is designed to get me i range or products ordered by discount card users from orders information. When i first wrote it, it seemed to work fine, but recently i've been told that it freezes, and i have no idea why. I tried to play with it a little, and it seems that when i add the date range, or even just single date search condition, it freezes(can show that 'Loading' popup in PHPMyAdmin forever); other that that, it takes around 1 second to execute.

[Here's what EXLAIN gives me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADqZs.jpg)

Comment: Why are you using distinct at outer query. Try it in inner query where you think possible duplicates are coming from

Comment: ALso why are we joining Customer and Discount_Card table when we are not fetching any columns from there?

Comment: How do you execute this, using php ?

Comment: Coz if it's in sql execution context, the start_date variable and end_date variable are not in the exact format. (Normally it should be like @start_date)

Comment: Yeah, i use this in a PHP script. it just fetches data and then outputs it into a file. Most of the joins are here cause for example table Discount_card helps determine whether the user has a discount card registered.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, apparently throwing out inner join for Discount_cards and replacing it with a WHERE IN fixes this problem:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    Products.Product_name
    FROM Order_details
    INNER JOIN Products
    ON Products.Product_codenumber = Order_details.Product_codenumber
    INNER JOIN Orders
    ON Order_details.Order_ID = Orders.Order_ID
    INNER JOIN Customers
    ON Orders.Customer_ID = Customers.Customer_ID
    WHERE 
    Customers.Login IN (
        SELECT
        Phone_number
        FROM Discount_cards
        )
    AND Orders.Status_ID = '5'
    AND (DATE(Orders.Time) BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date')
```

I wonder why did that freeze happen though, explanation would be appreciated.